# Does npx create-react-app install node_modules globally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I started my first react app (a small beginner tutorial )today using CRA.
Size of the initial boiler was around 150 mB.
I used the npx command for the same.

Now do I have install all the node_modules again for a different project?
If that is the case should I install CRA globally using npm install -g  instead?
Downloading the same modules again everytime seems like a waste of time and space if someone plans on creating multiple react applications.

In the documentation for CRA npx was suggested and for users who had previously installed CRA globally using npm i -g, uninstallation was recommended.

What are the downsides to installing CRA globally?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: one downside of installing cra globally is that you have to update cra  every while to get the latest version of react and other libraries while with npx whenever you create a new project you get all latest libraries.

Comment: @angelo updates will take much less time right? Isn't it better to do update than to download everything again. My main concern is the space wastage. Are there any other downsides ?

Comment: one more downside is deploying. It will be quite difficult to deploy the app and also it will make your code difficult to be used by other developers.